# Creating GraphQL Search query using React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, express, graphql, graphql-js

I am trying to implement a search query to help me search by name or category. I need help with only the backend part of it which is setting up the resolver and the index which im not sure if I m doing it right

Resolver.js

```
//search for single user
    user: async ({_id}) => {
        try {
            const foundUser = await User.findOne({_id: _id})
            return foundUser;
        } catch (err){
            throw err;
        }
    },
//search for all users
    users: async () => {
        try{
            const users = await User.find()
            return users;
        } catch(err) {
            throw err;
        }
    },
```

I want to be able to search all users with the role "Star" and do the search only on those users. Not really sure where to go from here
Index.js

```
type User {
    _id: ID!
    username: String
    password: String
    name: String
    role: String
    enterCategory: String
}
//not sure if search is right
type RootQuery {
    user(_id: ID!): User!
    users: [User!]!
    searchStars(search: String): [Users]!
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Index.js

```
    searchCategories(search: String): [User]!
```

Resolver

```
 searchCategories: async ({ search }) => {
        try {
            const users = await User.find()
            return users.filter(x => x.enterCat === search);
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
```